Error: could not compile `sc-network` when bumping to v1.11.0
I'm encountering an issue with cargo build --release after updating a solo chain to Polkadot-SDK v1.11.0.


The error message appears when compiling 'sc-network' in the file located at: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/0d65b3f2db4f807e0e7a1d2aae0a672be6e93c63/substrate/client/network/src/litep2p/discovery.rs#L459
The issue involves 'KademliaEvent', which is defined in: https://github.com/paritytech/litep2p/blob/4b6f05b9bc64e2065f5ac622ec9f9ccf089867f8/src/protocol/libp2p/kademlia/handle.rs#L152.

Can someone clarify if this is a known bug with the new SDK version, or might there be an error in my setup or usage?

The problem is that litep2p is currently pulled in as a git dependency and this is not fixed to a specific commit.
You should be able to fix it locally for you by running the following command:
cargo update -p litep2p --precise b142c9eb611fb2fe78d2830266a3675b37299ceb

